# MFC: flickering issue with GDI+

Tags: mfc

I create a sample dialog application which has a circle drawn. Also on mouse move the circle will be re-drawn. I am providing my  code below. Its also compilable.

I tried using double buffering and erasebackground, i was not getting the flickering issue, but i observed that the drawining is not erased properly. So to erase, in OnPaint i wrote the erasing code. Again i am facing the flickering issue.

```
void CPOCDlg::OnPaint()
{
    CPaintDC dc(this);
    GetClientRect(&clientRect);


    circle = clientRect;
    circle.DeflateRect(100,100);
    dc.SelectStockObject(NULL_BRUSH);
    dc.SelectStockObject(NULL_PEN);
    dc.FillSolidRect(circle, ::GetSysColor(COLOR_BTNFACE));

    Bitmap buffer(circle.right, circle.bottom);
    Graphics graphicsbuf(&buffer);
    Graphics graphics(dc.m_hDC);
    graphicsbuf.SetSmoothingMode(SmoothingModeHighQuality);

    SolidBrush brush(Color(255,71,71,71));
    Pen bluePen(Color(255, 0, 0, 255),1);

    graphicsbuf.DrawEllipse(&bluePen,Rect(circle.left,circle.top,circle.Width(),circle.Height()));
    graphicsbuf.SetSmoothingMode(SmoothingModeHighQuality);
    graphics.DrawImage(&buffer, 0, 0);

}

void CPOCDlg::OnMouseMove(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{
    m_point = point;
    InvalidateRect(circle,FALSE);

    CDialogEx::OnMouseMove(nFlags, point);
}


BOOL CPOCDlg::OnEraseBkgnd(CDC* pDC)
{
    return TRUE;
}
```

Please let me know if i am doing any mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use so called **double buffer** technique to prevent flickering:

```
// create Mem DC
dcMemory = new CDC;
dcMemory->CreateCompatibleDC(pDC);
pDC->SetMapMode(MM_TEXT);
dcMemory->SetMapMode(MM_TEXT);

// TODO: draw to memDC here

//switch back to paint dc
pDC->BitBlt(rectDirty.left, rectDirty.top, 
rectDirty.Width(), rectDirty.Height(), 
dcMemory, 
rectDirty.left,rectDirty.top,SRCCOPY);

dcMemory->DeleteDC();
delete dcMemory;
dcMemory = NULL;
```

Comment: Hi, I need to use GDI_ double buffering. i used it as below, but still the same issue. Can you please help on this.                             Bitmap buffer(circle.right, circle.bottom);
    Graphics graphicsbuf(&buffer);
    Graphics graphics(dc.m_hDC);
    graphicsbuf.SetSmoothingMode(SmoothingModeHighQuality);

    SolidBrush brush(Color(255,71,71,71));
    Pen bluePen(Color(255, 0, 0, 255),1);

    graphicsbuf.DrawEllipse(&bluePen,Rect(circle.left,circle.top,circle.Width(),circle.Height()));
    graphicsbuf.SetSmoothingMode(SmoothingModeHighQuality);
    graphics.DrawImage(&buffer, 0, 0);

Comment: You should use raw GDI stuff for double buffering, but GDI+ for actual drawing